# Restore formulas VBA code

Tags: excel, vba

So I have this Issue with making a button in Excel that restores all formulas. The formulas are all based on this one cell, currently **`A26 (=Demand!A2)`**. But since the row numbers will change in the future the code is currently not robust enough.

What it needs to do is type into the cell ***below*** the 'header' named "`FCST_ID`" the following formula: **`=Demand!A2`**. (keep in mind it's not a table) After it should select this whole row, filled with many formulas based on that **`=Demand!A2`** cell and pull it completely down until row 6000.

It works when I try to use a macro and select cell `A26`, however this doesn't make the model robust enough in case this cell would change to `A25` for example. So what I tried to do now is recording a macro that looks-up the 'header' `FCST_ID` and then goes one cell lower, fills in the formula and then pulls down all formulas from that row until row 6000.

Would highly appreciate any help!

```
Cells.Find(What:="FCST_ID", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate .Offset(1, 0).Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=Demand!R[-24]C"
Range("A26").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Range("A26:EU26").Select
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll ToRight:=2
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("A26:EU6000"), Type:=xlFillDefault
Range("A26:EU6000").Select
```

Comment: The recorded macro brings along several useless lines (such as the several scroll-up at the end). Would you mind cleaning a bit your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are trying (**Untested**)? I am assuming the `FCST_ID` is in Col A.

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim aCell As Range

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    With ws
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Cells) <> 0 Then
            lRow = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                          After:=.Range("A1"), _
                          Lookat:=xlPart, _
                          LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                          SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                          SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                          MatchCase:=False).Row

            Set aCell = .Cells.Find(What:="FCST_ID", LookIn:=xlValues, _
                        Lookat:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

            If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
                aCell.Offset(1).Formula = "=Demand!A2"

                .Range("A" & (aCell.Row+1) & ":EU" & (aCell.Row+1)).AutoFill _
                Destination:=.Range("A" & (aCell.Row+1) & ":EU" & lRow), Type:=xlFillDefault
            End If
        End If

    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: You do want the autofill because it's not just column A that's being filled down.

Comment: Can I borrow your Coffee? :P

Comment: What happened now is that all my headers were pulled down until row 6000. It should instead search for header 'FCST_ID' and then one cell beneath that header, fill in the formula "=Demand!A2". 

After, the row in which "=Demand!A2" was filled in must be pulled down until row 6000.

Thanks!

Comment: Made a minor change. Please test it now